# Splitting JSON objects in a file

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to find a way to split each object from each other. But when I save them into a json file, they come out all together and it's a mess.

My file comes out looking like this:

[image: and I guess they're unreadable like this]

I already tried some solutions, but to no avail

```js
if (status == google.maps.places.PlacesServiceStatus.OK)
  {
    let element = document.createElement('a');

    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++)
    {
      //console.log('after / to createMarker');

      createMarker(results[i]);

      //console.log (results);

      //var jsonData = JSON.stringify(createMarker.json);
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(results).split('},{').join('}, {'));
      //console.log(JSON.stringify(results).replace(/},{/g,'}, {'));

      // var jsonData = JSON.stringify(results);
      var jsonData = JSON.stringify(results).split('},{').join('}, {')
      var filename = 'ficheirojson.json'

      //console.log(results[0].formatted_address); //undefined
    }

    element.setAttribute('href', 'data:text/plain;charset=utf-8,' + encodeURIComponent(jsonData));
    element.setAttribute('download', filename);
    element.style.display = 'none';

    document.body.appendChild(element);

    element.click();

    document.body.removeChild(element);

  }
}
```

```
var json =
      {
        "nome": details.name,
        "morada": details.formatted_address,
        "coordenadas":
        {
          "latitude": latitude,
          "longitude": longitude
        }
      };
```

And I want something pretty and readable by the code like this:

> {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}, {"name":"John", "age":30,
>   "car":null}, {"name":"John", "age":30, "car":null}, {"name":"John",
>   "age":30, "car":null}

where each object is in a different line

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the overloads provided in `.stringify` object.

That would mean you need to replace:

`JSON.stringify(results).split('},{').join('}, {')`

To:

`JSON.stringify(results, null, '\t');`

This will use tab character to mimic standard pretty-print appearance.

```js
console.log(JSON.stringify({ uno: 1, dos: 2 }, null, '\t'));
```

See [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#The_space_argument) for more details.

Comment: exactly what i wanted. Thanks!